# Definition of the complex $\log^z z$ to know the solutions of $\Re \log^x x=\Im \log^x x$ when $x$ runs over the reals between $0$ and $1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

I would like to know a draft to refresh how to define the complex function $$f(z)=\log^z z,\tag{1}$$
here thus $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Is required a definition of our logarithm here in a way that my purpose explained in next paragraphs has mathematical meaning.

My question arises when I was playing with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) with the code

`plot log^x x, from x=0 to 1`

The exercise that I would like to know in my home is to calculate the corresponding real and imaginary parts $\Re \log^x x$ and $\Im \log^x x$, over the real ray $x>0$, with the purpose to know how many solutions has the equation $$\Re \log^x x=\Im \log^x x\tag{2}$$
over the real segment $0<x\leq 1$ (it is easy to see that the real $x=1$ is a solution, but I would like to know/prove all solutions over reals between $0$ and $1$).

> **Question.** In previous context, can you refresh to me how to define the complex function $$f(z)=\log^z z?$$
>   Only is required hints, and the definition of previous complex $\log^z z$ is according my purpose to know how many solutions has the equation $\Re \log^x x=\Im \log^x x$ for reals $0<x\leq 1$ . **Many thanks.**

Thus I need hints or details to get a definition/expresion for $f(z)$, and from here I can to calculate its imaginary and real parts.

Comment: For complex $w$ and a choice $\log$ of branch of logarithm, we can define $w^{\zeta} := \exp(\zeta \log w)$.

Comment: That is, I need a good definition of the branch of the complex logarithmm @Travis

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Branches_of_the_complex_logarithm , but you've already implicitly chosen one just by writing down the expression $\log z$ in the first place.

Comment: Many thanks really I need a good refresh of complex analysis @Travis